# I have given correct path for favicon in Reactjs website but favicon not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

Favicon is present in assets folder with name fav.png but not showing in browse

I'm attaching screenshot link for package.json file screenshot, favicon link line screenshot and favicon showing in browser screenshot.

package.json screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUKxj.png

favicon link file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmfKf.png

favicon showing in browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3paL.png

Comment: First of all, try to open your favicon like this: example.com/fav.png and press ctrl + f5

Secondly, convert your fav.png into ico format.

Thirdly, make sure that you use the right attribute (`rel="shortcut icon"`) for your "link" meta tag.

Comment: i tried all steps but nothing happend

Answer (score 2):

for favicon please convert your `png` logo to `.ico` file and place it in `public` 
folder.

check the `index.html` file for `favicon link` react selected.

after change maybe you see the last favicon but maybe it cause by `caches`, Then `clear your cache` and `refresh` the page.

good luck

Comment: nothing happened. even i clear cache but nothing happened